# How to make the output of a list index start with 1?

Tags: list, indexing

I have 2 lists. the first is:
`city_indices = list(range(0 , len(cities)))` # There are 12 cities in that list

Its output is:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

The second list is the city names:

```
city_names = ['Buenos Aires',
 'Toronto',
 'Marakesh',
 'Albuquerque',
 'Los Cabos',
 'Greenville',
 'Archipelago Sea',
 'Pyeongchang',
 'Walla Walla Valley',
 'Salina Island',
 'Solta',
 'Iguazu Falls'
]
```

I have to put the result of combining the two lists in a variable, `names_and_ranks = []`

The code I have to combine the lists is:

```
for index in list(range(0,len(cities))):
       print(f'{city_indices[index]}' '. ', city_names[index])
```

its output:

0. Buenos Aires
1. Toronto
2. Marakesh
3. Albuquerque
4. Los Cabos
5. Greenville
6. Archipelago Sea
7. Pyeongchang
8. Walla Walla Valley
9. Salina Island
10. Solta
11. Iguazu Falls

Here's where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to start the list with 1. and end in 12 or how to put the whole thing in `names_and_ranks = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add 1 to `city_indices[index]`:

```
for index in list(range(0,len(city_names))):
    print(f'{city_indices[index] + 1}' '. ', city_names[index])
```

Output:

```
1.  Buenos Aires
2.  Toronto
3.  Marakesh
4.  Albuquerque
5.  Los Cabos
6.  Greenville
7.  Archipelago Sea
8.  Pyeongchang
9.  Walla Walla Valley
10.  Salina Island
11.  Solta
12.  Iguazu Falls
```

Comment: I will do that, for sure, Sushil. I’m still unsure how to put it all into names_and_ranks = [ ]

Comment: Can u elaborate more on what u wanna do?

Comment: I came up with this solution:                                                             names_and_ranks = [ ]
for index in range(0,len(cities)):
    names_and_ranks.append(f'{city_indices[index] + 1}' + '. ' + city_names[index])
print(names_and_ranks)       It seemed to work nicely. Let me know if that doesn't make it more clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry @Sushil, forgot to check your answer as correct until now. Thanks for your help